# How to use jinja tags inside Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

Let's say i need to have the javascript in a seperate file, then how can i add a `{{variable}}` for example in the javascript file without having to use a `<script>` tag in the HTML?

Is that even possible with jinja?

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited to generating HTML files with Jinja. You can generate a JS file that uses a `{{ variable }}`.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: The same way you generate an HTML file from a Jinja template, except the destination is a JS file. We'd need to know more about your setup. The point is, Jinja is not an HTML generator — it is a templating engine. The final documents can be any type of textual file.

Comment: I figured it out from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917471/pass-parameter-with-python-flask-in-external-javascript thanks anyway